# What does it mean to "put on one's face"?

Tags: expressions

In the movie "Hook", there is a scene where a lady with lots of make-up says something along these lines to other ladies of similar looks:

> Girls, here he comes! Put on your faces!

Up until that moment, I had always assumed that "putting on one's face" refers to putting makeup on it. But now I'm unsure. Maybe it actually refers to "putting on a show for somebody", such as acting all surprised/fawning over somebody who wants to feel important? It seems like it would be utterly impossible for the ladies to "put on makeup" in less than a few seconds between her saying it and the captain arriving there, so this leads me to believe that it has nothing to do with makeup after all, and more about the expression of one's face.

I tried Wiktionary on "putting on one's face" before asking here.

Comment: I think you need to quote the context in full. There are two expressions which mean, as you point out, two different things : applying makeup or using the face as a mask to express something that is not inherent to the person.

Comment: With one meaning it's similar to *I know you're all a bit disappointed, but put on a happy face when he comes in.*

Comment: This is clearly to put on make-up.

Comment: @Lambie Except the context seems to be that they already have their makeup on.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a brothel, and the woman is the madame calling to her ladies. So she's probably telling them to put on smiling faces to entice the customers.